# How to write Custom Format for Number in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am using an SSRS report to export data into Excel. But after exporting to Excel, I am getting green arrows in each numeric cell with the below error,

> Number Stored as Text
>
> Convert to Number (After clicking this arrow it goes invisible).

Below is my sample data,

[image: Data]

My data is separated with commas.  It can have a percentage (%), decimals (.) and it can be negative.

I am using the below expression:

```
=iif((IsNothing(Fields!Feb.Value) = false And Fields!Category.Value <> "Inventory"),
(
iif(Fields!Category.Value.ToString().Contains("%"), 
(Format(Fields!Feb.Value,"###,##0.0")) & "%", 
Format(Fields!Feb.Value/1000,"###,##0.0")))
, "")
```

If I remove the expression and set number property of the placeholder, then green arrow do not show up.

I feel that I can solve this issue by adding a custom format in my placeholder properties, but I have no idea what expression I need to add which can handle all conditions as my current expression.

Comment: try to choose the data format in the cell properties? in your case, choose a one from `Number` catagroy

Comment: There is no place where I can select LONG type in Number tab.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use this article to solve problem? "http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=38371"

Comment: you could create your own Marco to do that which is the way shown in that link

Comment: I created same methods in report property -> code section. But it's giving me Error as "[rsCompilerErrorInCode] There is an error on line 0 of custom code: [BC30627] 'Option' statements must precede any declarations or 'Imports' statements."

Comment: Solved by setting format property.